# Is there a way to check what program is connecting to a socket?

Tags: java, sockets, security, servlets

Is there a way, in java to check what type of program is connecting to a server socket. I have an example server, which is a basic 1 page web server. But I only want to allow connections from specific applications. Such as web browsers. Because I don't want anyone to have a random program and connect to my server to try and hack it. I have researched and have not been successful. If you would like my project's details, please go to https://github.com/sebagius7110/ServerSebs

All I need to do is on a connection, if the program for example is google chrome, it lets the connection through. But for example it needs to make sure it has a web interface, so no one can just randomly make an application called google chrome and connect to it. This is a security question.

***I know this is a long question, and a hard one, but thanks in advance.***

Comment: I remember reading about a solution to this problem used to avoid censorship in china.  You require the connecting program to send a special message before you respond at all.  Otherwise you say nothing.  You may have to use UDP to get this started because TCP doesn't negotiate a connection that way.  UDP could be used to update a IP whitelist that would then allow normal TCP connections.  The trick then becomes how you keep your special message a secret.

Comment: This might be worth looking at: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/826/how-can-i-securely-authenticate-the-client-application-sending-me-data

Comment: @CandiedOrange UDP hole punching doesn't really help here, since the question is about how to distinguish between Chrome and a program faking to be Chrome (which is impossible).

Comment: @Kayaman Was attempting to show that the hard problem isn't about connection protocol, which is a solvable problem.  The hard problem is, as I said, keeping your "special message" a secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to check what program is connecting to a socket?

No there isn't a way.

At the socket level, there is no information available to the server as to what program is initiating the connection on the client side.

At the HTTP protocol level, there is provision for information in the HTTP Request message to identify the kind of "user agent" that the request comes from.  However this is not reliable.  Someone who is trying to hack you is liable to put misleading information into the User-Agent header.

In short, this approach to preventing hacks will not be effective, and is probably not even worth the effort of implementing.

And besides ... what is to stop someone using (say) the real Google Chrome application as their hacking tool?

(The same answer applies, no matter what programming language you are using ...)

Comment: netrek used to try to do this with "blessed" client binaries that would send response when asked by the server.  It was supposed to keep people from using auto aiming clients.  People just pulled a man-in-the-middle attack.  They added server code to their hacked clients and asked the blessed client whatever the real server asked them.  Then they turned around and offered whatever response they got.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of a way to provide unspoofable identification of software that doesn't rely on trusting the platform on which it runs.  In short, the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: @StephenC you're right. If you know what the other end expects and send that, there's no way for the other end to detect that it's not talking to what it thinks it's talking to.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can disguise as Google Chrome or any other User agent.

I think the requirement you have is the support for Denial Of Service (DOS). You have to looks at the DOS supported by various web containers. This is container specific.

DOS allows you put restrictions on the incoming requests. In your case, one of your restriction parameter is the User-Agent. You should allow the User-Agents that you are interested in.